# Which approach to use when finding min and max value in array?

Tags: c

I wonder what is the best way to find min and max value in array. I use two approaches (my array is `a` with size `size`):

Approach 1:

```
int min = 0, max = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > max || i == 0) max = a[i];
    if(a[i] < min || i == 0) min = a[i];
}
```

Approach 2:

```
int min = INT_MAX, max = INT_MIN;
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    if(a[i] < min) min = a[i];
}
```

Approach 3:

```
int min = a[0], max = a[0];
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    if(a[i] < min) min = a[i];
}
```

Approach 2 seems a little bit more optimal to my newbie eye (we don't have to evaluate `i == 0` 2 times every loop iteration. However, I am afraid that playing with these limit values might go wrong. This is solved in approach 3, though. Which is the most optimal of the three and why?

Thanks for all replies!

Comment: #3 is the way to go.

Comment: I really like that you think to iterate only once.Well done.I'll take 2 or 3

Comment: @Cid `max` and `min` won't be undefined, I'm defining them as 0 before loop, but as you say - for `i == 0` condition `a[i] > max` won't be checked.

Comment: This seems more of a code review question with optimisation aspect. "opinion-based" seems the closest close-vote reason.

Comment: Approach 3 can be improved with `if(a[i] < min)` --> `else if(a[i] < min)`

Comment: Approach 3 is wrong when `size == 0` as it has undefined behavior. (Does not apply to an _array_ though, but to allocated memory.)

Answer (score 3):

Try to go for the 3rd option. It is more optimal and then you don't have to deal with the limits values.

Answer (score 3):

Approach 1 suites all cases, so if you are writing code with no regard to special context, I would use it.

Approach 2 depends on type of variable. If you change it from `int32` to whatever, you would have to rewrite the program. And btw for unsigned types `0` is minimum value and no special constant can be defined.

Approach 3 requires that you sequence (array) is not empty and cannot be used without additional length-checking.

I like this modification of Approach 3:

```
// assuming size is of size_t and can't be negative
int min = size ? a[0] : 0;
int max = min;
for(int i = 1; i < size; i++)
{
    if(a[i] > max) max = a[i];
    if(a[i] < min) min = a[i];
}
```

### UPD

I am really surprised to see people think Approach 1 wont work on negative numbers. It **will** because on first iteration, when `i==0` is checked, we always init `min` and `max` with first element. In case of doubts I recommend running this code on negative sequence - it works (I've checked)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187150/discussion-on-answer-by-grapes-which-approach-to-use-when-finding-min-and-max-va).

Answer (score 1):

2nd and 3rd approaches are better approaches. Personally I feel 3rd one is better solution than 2nd solution.

Comment: optimal means, starting with the initial value from array is good is what I mean

Comment: There is no such thing like "more optimal". Something is "optimal" or it is not. There is nothing better than "optimal" so nothing can be "more optimal". ... is what @DavideSpataro tried to tell you.

Comment: Yes, sorry I should use proper word. it's better way to do, not more optimal. is this fine?